# R Error - "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Tags: r

I'm trying to design a simple function to return profit based on n units produced.

I use the following code to run 1000 simulations of demand according to some given parameters:

```
nsims=1000
sim.demand=rep(NA,nsims)
  for(i in 1:nsims){
  sim.demand[i]=rnorm(12, 12000, sd=3496.752) 
}
```

I then define a profit function as a function of n units produced:

```
profit <- function(n)
 for(i in 1:1000){
   if(sim.demand[i]<=n) 
     profit[i]=-100000-(80*n)+100*sim.demand[i]+30*(n-sim.demand[i]) else
     profit[i]=-100000-(80*n)+100*n
}
```

When I try to find profit at 10000 units, for example, I type in profit(10000). But I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in profit[i] = -1e+05 - (80 * n) + 100 * n : 
object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are getting this because there are no objects within `profit` (i.e., you can' subset this). What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to model profit. $100000 fixed cost, $80 variable cost, $100 sale price, $30 salvage value for all unsold product. I'm trying to create the function so that I can write "profit(10000)" and it would return the profit if I were to produce 10000 units under these parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling profit[i], where profit is a function, and you don't want to subset a function. I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, but I think you want to create a new variable to return at the end of the function. So, something like:

```
profit <- function(n){
  return_profit<-rep(NA, 1000)
  for(i in 1:1000){
    if(sim.demand[i]<=n) {
      return_profit[i]=-100000-(80*n)+100*sim.demand[i]+30*(n-sim.demand[i])
    } 
    else{
      return_profit[i]=-100000-(80*n)+100*n
    }
  }
  return_profit
}
```

?

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you! I tried to vote this answer up, but I need more reputation. I appreciate all the help!